# Can 'repercuss' be used as a verb?

Tags: meaning, verbs, word-usage, is-it-a-verb

Lord Owen, the former British Foreign Secretary, in a BBC interview tonight with Jeremy Paxman  used the word 'repercuss' as a verb. It was with reference to President Obama's handshake with  Raul Castro at the Memorial Service for Nelson Mandela.

David Owen said 'It is bound to repercuss', presumably meaning 'There are bound to be repercussions'. However, whilst 'repercussion'implies an unfavourable side effect, Owen had been at pains to stress the inevitability of America's due-course normalisation of its relations with Cuba, and other than in the use of this one word he made no suggestion that any harm would come of it.

So what are we to make of 'repercuss' as a verb? The Oxford Dictionary of English doesn't recognise it.

Comment: Is this a real question or a peeve?

Comment: @TimLymington It smells like a peeve, but it’s also a prevarication, because the assertion that the OED does not recognize it is demonstrably false.

Comment: Would you have preferred the more etymologically wholesome (as it were) _repercute_?

Comment: It can be a peeve and a real question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Most recent OED citation for ***repercute*** *v. Obs. rare.* is: **“1578 Banister** *Hist. Man* i. 11 — When the first bone, percussed by the stroke of the ayre, repercuteth the other in manner of a mallet.” Unless we’re intentionally calquing from French *répercuter* or Spanish *repercutir*, it seems a trifle recherché in modern English, *n’est-ce pas?*

Comment: http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=repercuss

Comment: @tchrist It 'smells' to me as if you need a pair of spectacles!

Answer (score 1):

The OED does so recognize it; I don’t know why you pretend otherwise.

The first OED citation for ***repercuss*** *v*. is from 1501 and the last ones are from the lattermost part of the 20th century.

Those were transitive uses.

The OED notes that the intransitive sense dates only from the first quarter of the 20th century, and is a back-formation from *repercussion*.

Comment: Who said it wasn't in the OED?

Comment: @WS2 You yourself did so.

Comment: I never at any point mentioned the OED.